# How can I get Excel to use conditional formatting per day of the week using dates and not the words "Monday, Tuesday,"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting

I am working on a delivery schedule for the company I work for and we want to be able to have the dates color coded by days of the week.  But we often have several deliveries on the same date, so when I tried to use the weekday function it did not work. The column may look like:

[image]

I want it to be so that every Monday is a color, every Tuesday ect.
I used the formula =$a4=Datevalue("1/12/23") for hightlighting the first day but I have no idea how to make it then hightlight every other date that is the same day of the week, like counting by multiples of seven but with dates

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Your image didn't successfully save.  Please edit the question to fix.

Answer (score 1):

##### [WEEKDAY Function](https://superuser.com/questions/1768022/how-can-i-get-excel-to-use-conditional-formatting-per-day-of-the-week-using-date/1768023?noredirect=1#comment2752572_1768023%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a)

Returns the day of the week corresponding to a date. The day is given as an integer, ranging from 1 (Sunday) to 7 (Saturday), by default. `WEEKDAY(serial_number,[return_type])`

###### Conditional Formatting Formula

```
=WEEKDAY(<date>)=<[1-7]>
```

| Day | Test Date in `A4` |
| --- | --- |
| Sunday | `=WEEKDAY(A4)=1` |
| Monday | `=WEEKDAY(A4)=2` |
| Tuesday | `=WEEKDAY(A4)=3` |
| Wednesday | `=WEEKDAY(A4)=4` |
| Thursday | `=WEEKDAY(A4)=5` |
| Friday | `=WEEKDAY(A4)=6` |
| Saturday | `=WEEKDAY(A4)=7` |

*<sup>Credit @Ron_Rosenfeld ([comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1768022/how-can-i-get-excel-to-use-conditional-formatting-per-day-of-the-week-using-date/1768023?noredirect=1#comment2752572_1768023%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weekday-function-60e44483-2ed1-439f-8bd0-e404c190949a)) for noting `WEEKDAY(<date>)=<[1-7]>` returns TRUE/FALSE without needing to wrap it in an `IF` statement.</sup>*

Comment: this worked thank you so so much!

Comment: @BlindSpots ,,, nice one + 10☺

Comment: Suggestion:  The `IF` function is unnecessary. `=WEEKDAY(A4)=1` by itself will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: Excellent. I'll improve my answer.